# Xamarin.New blank Cross-platform App(Native Portable) can't start running

Tags: xamarin, building

I have created new cross-platform Blank App(Native Portable), but the app was not running.

I got output message:

Android application is debugging.
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration

I'm sure that MainLauncher is set True and this project is set to Deploy.
I've already installed the Android SDK platform for API Level 17,19 and 23.

Application setup:
[image]

Xamarin version:
[image]

Could you please give me any solution to resolve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to deploy to a device or simulator?

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it.

Comment: @RimVo please tell us how so you can help others with this problem.

Comment: Following this link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/ I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this problem. Usually minor problems in Xamarin can be solved by cleaning and rebuilding whole solution.